# Magento multi store user registration

Tags: magento

I am trying to build a multistore in **Magento**.

I want to know what if the User credentials in multistore are same or not.
Say I'm having store1.com and store2.com.If user register on store1.com, and then try to register on store2.com with same credentials, will he be able to register or he will be shown already registerd.

Answer (score 0):

It's a configuration from Stores => Configuration => Customers => Customer configuration => Account sharing option.

On *Share Customer Accounts* configuration, you can choose to share customers or not.